# Public function not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, function, public

I have the following two pieces of code, please take a look at it, I pointed where it is going wrong.
I removed the functions where I call the second window, they do not make sense here.

First, main form, this form calls the second form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace STP_Design
{
    public partial class STP2Main : Form
    {
        public STP2Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPageDeviceManager;
        }
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MenuForm MDIMF = new MenuForm();
            MDIMF.MdiParent = this;
            MDIMF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            MDIMF.Location = new Point(3, 50);
            MDIMF.Show();
            tabControl1.Visible = false;
        }

        public void set()
        {
            tabControl1.Visible = true; // This statement executes, but does not result in anything I'd expect. The debugger tells me the visibility is false.
            tabControl1.BringToFront();
        }
   }
}
```

and second form, which I close and should update the first form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace STP_Design
{
    public partial class MenuForm : Form
    {
        public MenuForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BringToFront();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            STP2Main stp = new STP2Main();
            stp.set();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the behavior that you see?

Comment: The "calling the second window" code might be pretty important.

Comment: Where is the code where you actually show STP2Main?

Comment: I made my tabcontrol box invisible when opening the second form, if I close the form, and try to make the tabcontrol visible, it does not appear at all. I set a breakpoint on the line which should set the visibility. It says its invisible (thats right) but remains invisible ...

Comment: I'll add some more code, 1 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `set` method on a *new* version of the main form, rather than on the version you presumably already have displayed to the user.

What you need to do is get the *current* main form from the `MdiParent` property of the menu form, and call the method on *that* instead.

```
// In menu form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mainForm = this.MdiParent as STP2Main;
    if (mainForm != null)
        mainForm.set();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: OK, so i should change "STP2Main stp = new STP2Main();" to " public STP2Main MainForm { get; set; }". When I do that, i get a null reference error on "MainForm.Set();"

Comment: @2pietjuh2 I've changed my code to match the code you posted, hopefully this should work for you.